# two array of different object multiplication

Tags: c#

I have two list of Object in C#:

1. roomlist = `[{roomID = 1}, {roomID = 2}]`
2. companyList = `[{companyID = x}, {companyID = y}, {companyID = z}]`

and I wanna have the output like this:

```
combList = [{roomID = 1, companyID = x}, {roomID = 1, companyID = y}, {roomID = 1, companyID = z}, {roomID = 2, companyID = x}, ...]
```

I have used foreach to create the combList
but the problem is that the roomList and companyList are too large and it takes lots of time to create the combList
is there any other solution?

Comment: So the solution you currently have works but takes too long? Is that what im understanding?

Comment: yes that's the problem @JosipJuros

Comment: Perhaps you want to create an enumerator rather than materialize a whole list up front? `roomlist.SelectMany(r => companyList, (r, c) => select new {roomID = r.roomID, companyID = c.companyID})`

Comment: Then I would suggest doing a LINQ/Lambda expression to get this done, rather than a for each loop.

Comment: Show us your code. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

What you're after here is known as the *cartesian product* of two lists - and as you've found, it's not feasible to generate all possible values and materialize/store them up front when the input sizes start growing.

Luckily, all the `LINQ` methods tend to produce *enumerables* - lazily generated collections - instead of materialized collections, so you can start working on the different combinations instead of waiting for the whole range to be generated:

```
var roomList = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new {roomID = i});
var companyList = "x y z".Split().Select(s => new {companyID = s});

var combEnumerables = roomList.SelectMany(room => companyList, (r, c) => new {roomID = r.roomID, companyID = c.companyID});

foreach(var combo in combEnumerables)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"We could assign room {combo.roomID} to company {combo.companyID}");
}
```